# What is maximum length of AWS ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I found couple mentions of limits in the documentation:

[apigateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) - ARN length of a method with authorization    1600 bytes

[API_Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_Role.html) - Maximum length of 2048

But is it possible to get ARN with 4000 characters or even more?

I need this to store in local DB, and I don't want to use something like MaxValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any official source specifying a maximum possible length of an ARN.  ARNs are primarily constrained by the length constraints on their componenents, specifically the resource, which varies in format and content from service to service.  2048 seems like a very safe value, as it is difficult if not impossible to imaging a circumstance where an ARN would need to be that long.

See [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and AWS Service Namespaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) for typical example ARNs.  If there were a meaningful global maximum size of ARNs, this is where it *should* have been documented.

Comment: Official spec is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_Role.html   And yes, its 2048

Comment: @Yohst that link is mentioned in the original question.  Taken in context, that page only provides the maximum length of an IAM Role's ARN -- it does not document a global constraint on the limit of all ARNs across all services, everywhere.  At this point I have to stand by my original answer that the global maximum possible ARN length for any service is not documented.

Comment: forgive me but the link i provided seems different from yours. "my link" states: Arn: The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) specifying the role. For more information about ARNs and how to use them in policies, see IAM Identifiers in the IAM User Guide guide.   Length Constraints: Minimum length of 20. Maximum length of 2048.   Am I not reading this right?

Comment: @Yohst your link is mentioned in the *question* (not in my answer). The problem with this page is that it only documents the maximum length ARN accepted/provided by the IAM API as a **role ARN** -- which is only one of many varieties of ARN -- so it does not necessarily follow that every other type of ARN is necessarily subject to the same limits.  Indeed, some ARNs have shorter maximum lengths, such as method ARNs for API Gateway. Others might have longer maximums, but there is -- to my knowledge -- no authoritative documentation of the absolute maximum length of any ARN in *any* AWS service.